# Talk command only shows "Checking for invitation on caller's machine"

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, osx-yosemite, chat

The `talk` command on Yosemite doesn't work and the `/etc/inetd.conf` file is nowhere to be found. Why is this file no longer included with OS X and why doesn't talk work anymore?

Running `talk` just says:

```
Checking for invitation on caller's machine
```

Comment: Did you use it before? What is the full command you are using? And why do you think `/etc/inetd.conf` is related? If not related then please remove that part; we like one question per post in our Q&A format; please see the [tour].

Comment: the `inetd.conf` file is related because an explanation I saw on MacHints from 2002 explains how to enable `talk`.

Comment: Please add those details to your question. (And also the answers to my other questions above.)

Answer (score 5):

The information you require about getting `/usr/bin/talk` working in Yosemite can be found in the `ntalkd(8)` man page.

An excerpt from that page reads:

```
Execute the following command as root to enable talkd:

   launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ntalk.plist
```

I did this, and was then able to issue a `talk nevin` command in one Terminal window, and received the following notice in another Terminal window:

```
Message from Talk_Daemon@nevin-mac-mini.local at 23:46 on 2015/09/14 ...  
talk: connection requested by nevin@localhost                             
talk: respond with:  talk nevin@localhost
```

Taking that action in the second terminal window gave me the familiar split-screen talk window.  There were no further "Waiting for invitation..." messages.

To turn off `ntalkd`, I used:

`launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ntalk.plist`

Comment: Does this work for anyone? (Using macOS 11.5.2) After `sudo launchctl load …` I try `talk cannyboy` and nothing happens (just get the CLI prompt again)

Comment: I just tried it on my Big Sur system;  the binaries and commands still seem to be there.